# Solved Subset Sum recursively with for loop and without.Why is version with for loop faster?

Tags: python, runtime, code-analysis, subset-sum

So I solved Subset Sum using two different methods. In the first I used a backtracking for loop method and in the second I use a backtracking technique without a forloop.
I've tried several random test and the version with the forloop out performs the version without it consistently. That goes against my intuition and against my analysis using the Masters Theorem.

Can someone please explain why my version with the forloop is faster. What am I missing?

```
def subset_sum_loop(idx , nums , sub_size , target , sum , cur):
        global S_res
        if sub_size == 0 and sum == target:
            S_res = True

        N = len(nums)
        for i in range(idx , N):

            if sum + nums[i] <= target:
                sum += nums[i]
                cur.append(nums[i])
                subset_sum_loop(i + 1 , nums , sub_size - 1 , target , sum, cur)
                sum -= nums[i]
                cur.pop()


        return S_res

def sub_sum_solo(idx , nums , sub_size, target , sum , cur):
    global S_res
    N = len(nums)
    if sub_size == 0 and target == sum:
        S_res = True
        return
    if idx >= N:
        return


    if sum + nums[idx] <= target:
        cur.append(nums[idx])
        sum += nums[idx]
        sub_sum_solo(idx + 1 , nums , sub_size - 1 , target , sum, cur)
        sum -= nums[idx]
        cur.pop()

    sub_sum_solo(idx + 1 , nums , sub_size , target , sum, cur)

    return S_res
```

Comment: "That goes ... against my analysis using the Masters Theorem." - why would your analysis using the master theorem make you not expect this? The master theorem only gives asymptotic runtime.

Comment: The method with the for loop has a greater run time. I could have made a mistake though. But, if you have a greater asymptotic runtime after a certain point you will always take longer than a method with a lesser asymptotic runtime so that's why I was confused when the lesser one consistently took longer. Am I missing something?

Comment: The asymptotic runtimes look equal to me.

Comment: How did you come up with the runtime for the one with the for loop? I was thinking you could come up with an upper bound with T(n) = n * T(n-1)

Comment: The ones with and without the loop do the same work.

Comment: (Also, this doesn't look like subset sum. Subset sum doesn't have a required subset cardinality.)